# Inverse of a 3x3 Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

So I know the definition of the Inverse of a Matrix A is that there exists matrix B such that AB=BA=I<sub>3</sub>, where I<sub>3</sub> is the identity matrix. If A is invertible, then the matrix B is called the inverse of the matrix A, and it is denoted by A<sup>-1</sup>.

I'm trying to find the inverse of a random 3x3 matrix A with integer coefficient (if it exists) without using the Inverse[...] function in *Mathematica*. So far I have:

```
A=Table[RandomInteger[],{i,3},{j,3}]
B=Table[x[i,j],{i,3},{j,3}]
```

And would have to solve for B, such that

```
A.B==B.A==I
```

I have no idea how to start and anything would be helpful.

Comment: "*without using the Inverse[...] function*" and "*I have no idea how to start*"  I think that these comments demonstrate that this is not a Mathematica question ... It is a linear algebra one.  Before you can do this in Mathematica, you must become familiar with the underlying mathematics.

Comment: I understand the actually Mathematics, but don't know how to start to code it for a random 3x3 matrix without finding the determinant, matrix of cofactors and then transposing.

Comment: If you are trying to implement a specific algorithm, describe that algorithm in the question.

Comment: I don't know if I meant to implement an algorithm as all I am given is that if
    A.B=B.A=I then B is said to be the inverse of A.

Comment: That makes it clear then that you need to get familiar with the background math first.  Methods for this are taught in all linear algebra courses, see e.g. [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix).

Comment: Can you do it for two by two matrices first?

Comment: be aware, the random matrix you've constructed has a high probability of being singular.

Answer (score 2):

```
MatrixForm[First[B /. Solve[A.B == IdentityMatrix[Length[A]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearSolve[A, IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[A]]]
```

Comment: *Technically*, `LinearSolve` is not `Inverse`. But is it really any different?